# Can I use Facebook API to add user to group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can someone please explain me, how can I use facebook API to add authorized user to a group? 
I see **/{user-id}/groups** and **/{group-id}** and not find any method to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the Graph API due to missing endpoints.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/groups#publish